# Proper way to measure an AC signal with an oscilloscope

Tags: ac, current-measurement, measurement, low-power, voltage-measurement

Is there a correct way to measure an AC source with an oscilloscope?
As shown in the schematic below,

[image]

I've got a current transducer that is expected to output an AC current of about +/- 1 mA (approx.), and when this current passes through the 10-ohm load resistance, is expected to measure +/- 10 mV.

The op-amp used as the voltage follower has a very low input bias current (~4 nA).

However, I was unable to observe any output with this setup.
Is there something incorrect with the way the AC signal is measured?

Comment: What is the CT P/N?

Comment: Have you measured the output of the CT with a DMM?

Comment: @Tony Stewart: The CT's P/N is C-CT-16, datasheet is here: http://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/copal-electronics-inc/C-CT-16/563-1392-ND/4428780

Comment: @uint128_t: Yes, I have tried to measure the AC output of the CT with a DMM, measuring AC but my meter was not able to measure in the 10's of mV in AC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specs CT: AC range 0.1~100 A  333.3 mV±1 % @ 100A into 10 Ω 50/60 Hz

```
 - primary turn = 1  Secondary turns=3000
```

- i.e. 300mA/mV so If you expect 10mV, then this would correspond to 3A
- Consider adding gain of x10 or x100 instead of x1 which serves no purpose from a low resistance.

> - Make sure only 1 wire is inserted in core. (line or neutral, I prefer neutral around DC circuit)
> - Using both wires cancels out flux and net result is zero.

Comment: "Using both wires cancels out flux and net result is zero." Okay, that is probably why I measured zero. I'll also take your suggestion of amplifying the signal. Thanks.